# Can dangling pointer be equal to valid pointer during constant evaluation in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, constexpr, dangling-pointer

During constant expression evaluation in C++17, shall the compiler consider any pointer addressing a valid object unequal to any pointer addressing an object after the end of its lifetime?

For example:

```
constexpr auto f(int * x = nullptr) {
    int c = 0;
    auto p = &c;
    if ( x == p )
        throw "unexpected";
    return p;
};

int main() {
    static_assert( f( f() ) );
}
```

Here the inner call of function `f()` returns a dangling pointer, which is passed to `f` again. I believed that the condition `x == p` must be `false` since `x` is a dangling pointer and `p` is a valid pointer, and it is indeed so in Clang. But in GCC the condition is satisfied and the constant evaluation fails due to `throw`. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ehcMro17q

Is it an undefined or implementation-defined behavior, or one of the compilers is wrong?

Comment: Here’s a simpler MWE that exposes the same behaviour, as far as I can tell: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sbsK6x775

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of comparing a dangling pointer with any other pointer is implementation-defined:

> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values.
> Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior.
> **Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.**

([[basic.stc]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc#4)) (equality comparison is included in “other use” here.)

As noted in the comments, even the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of the comparison operands invokes implementation-defined behaviour for the invalid pointer ([[conv.lval]/3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.lval#3.3)).

Unfortunately I can’t find anything that *mandates* lvalue-to-rvalue conversion for the operands of an equality comparison; [[expr.eq]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.eq#2) at best implies this very indirectly.

Comment: **The "allocator" result is implementation-defined; NEVER any "comparing" operator's result.** (Sorry for bringing this up again now, but I hope this to be more understandable. if spec makes a mistake, don't copy/paste silently)